# Contact Form in custom Theme

Tags: 7, theming, forms

I need to create one request information form that goes to each page in my website. That means I need to add that form into page.tpl.php page.

Form includes just basic information like name, email, phone, message and submit button.

So, what is the best practice to implement that form in my theme? I mean what are the steps to add form in Drupal?

I am new to Drupal and trying to learn it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't add a form in the page.tpl.php.

Instead define your own form in a block, and then place your block in every page (using Drupal standard block system or a contrib module such [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context)

To define your contact form you have two options:

- Use [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7): The form API allows you to create forms and react to submit of those forms. There are [plenty examples](https://www.drupal.org/node/1419390) of this. You will need to write your own module (easy), define your form in it and implement the block hooks to define a block that contains your custom form (you'll need at least [hook_block_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) and [hook_block_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7)).
- Use [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module: This module allows you define forms that users can submit and the submitted data can be emailed to the email addresses you want. You don't have to write code and you can theme them with your theme.

Also Drupal has a simple module with contact forms, but I think is only to contact  users.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Yes, this is Drupal 7.

I have created my own module for that form and activated that in my theme. It might sound silly but I don't know where and how should I include that so that it appears into all my page. 
Thanks,

Comment: You don't "enable" a module in a theme. You enable modules, and you can enable themes, but they are unrelated actions. If you have created your form you will need to add to a custom block with that form as the block content. I've updated my answer.